# File import issue in Python

Tags: python, import, importerror, modulenotfounderror

Here's my folder structure:

```
src
->deployment_pipeline
   ->__init__.py, train_pipeline.py
src
->dags
   ->__init__.py,airflow_dag.py
src
->db_connector_mlflow
   -> __init__.py, db_connector_mlflow.py
```

Now, I am trying to import a function start_final_train from train_pipeline.py(which is inside the folder deployment_pipeline) to airflow_dag.py and from db_connector_mlflow.py(which is inside the folder db_connector_mlflow) to airflow_dag.py

My import statement:

```
from deployment_pipeline import start_final_train
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deployment_pipeline'
```

Answer (score 0):

imports must be globally installed or be in the same directory or subdirectory thereof as your main file.

If you move your main file to the src folder and run everything from there it works out.

Your main file should import:

```
from dags.airflow_dag import <stuff you need from airflow_dag.py>
....
```

You should keep the same structure in airflow_dag.py to import your function (as if you were importing from src):

```
from deployment_pipeline.train_pipeline import start_final_train
```